# How to make function accept list of rules as an argument?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction, associations

Considering the list of rules:

```
r= {"a" -> "1", "b" -> "2", "c" -> 3, d -> 231, "e" -> 1.25};
```

I want to have a function `f[..._] := SomeFunction(key, value)` so that I can give `r` to `f`: `f[r]` and will do `SomeFunction(key, value)` on all elements of `r`.

p.s. Same question stands for Association.

Any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this would be a definition which does what you want for a list of rules:

```
f[r : {__Rule}] := someFunction @@@ r
```

and this would be one which handles the `Association` case:

```
f[a_Association] := someFunction @@@ Normal[a]
```

As mentioned by Gerli in a comment in version 10.1 one can also use `KeyValueMap` for the second case, for which that new function was added:

```
f[a_Association] := KeyValueMap[someFunction,a]
```

both assume that you want to return a list of returnvalues of `someFunction`...

Comment: In 10.1 you can also use `KeyValueMap` for associations, so the second definition would become `f[a_Association] := KeyValueMap[someFunction, a]`

Comment: @Gerli: good point, I somehow had in mind that I had seen this, but as I only have 10.0.2 installed I couldn't find it and I did not bother to search more. I have added it in my answer, thanks for pointing that out...

Answer (score 3):

```
r = {"a" -> "1", "b" -> "2", "c" -> 3, d -> 231, "e" -> 1.25};
someFunction[key_, value_] := {key, value}; (* say *)

f = someFunction @@@ # &
f@r
{{"a", "1"}, {"b", "2"}, {"c", 3}, {d, 231}, {"e", 1.25`}}
```